# changing column types across multiple tables and columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, type-conversion, iteration, column-types

I have several data frames that share the same column names.  For example...

dataframe A with column a,b,c  
 dataframe B with column c,d,e  
 dataframe C with column a,b,c,d

I want to convert columns named 'b' and 'c' to character(if these columns exist in the table). Can I achieve this without repeating like this

```
A$b <-as.character(A$b)
A$c <-as.character(A$c) 
B$b <-as.character(B$c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
charnames <- c('a','b','c','d','e')

indA <- colnames(A) %in% charnames
A[indA] <- lapply(A[indA], as.character)

indB <- colnames(B) %in% charnames
B[indB] <- lapply(B[indB], as.character)

# ...
```

This has the safeguard that if no column names match, the frame is unmodified.

If you are asking about automating even further than this, then I recommend organizing your frames away from individual variables, instead as a [`list`-of-`data.frame`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207).

Example of this:

```
lst <- list(indA, indB)
lst <- lapply(lst, function(df) {
  ind <- colnames(df) %in% charnames
  df[ind] <- lapply(df[ind], as.character)
  df
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful and yes I am looking to automating it further so I don't have to copy and paste above scripts. I defined a list of my data frames and used it as a variable in a loop function.. It did not quite work for me..Could you provide a bit more guide on how to do that? thanks again!

Comment: See my edit, hope it helps.